# How to set up symbols in WinDbg?

Tags: debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

I am using [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx) and I get the following error message when starting WinDbg / cdb or ntsd:

```
Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
```

When executing arbitrary commands, I also get the error message

```
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for <module>.<ext>
```

And the following seems to be related:

```
*********************************************************************
* Symbols can not be loaded because symbol path is not initialized. *
*                                                                   *
* The Symbol Path can be set by:                                    *
* using the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable.                   *
* using the -y <symbol_path> argument when starting the debugger.   *
* using .sympath and .sympath+                                      *
*********************************************************************
```

In a `!analyze -v` I have also seen

```
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
```

and

```
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
*** Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger      ***
*** doesn't have full symbol information. Unqualified symbol          ***
*** resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a      ***
*** fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution    ***
*** of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that        ***
*** enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol        ***
*** server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to        ***
*** appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect         ***
*** symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.        ***
***                                                                   ***
*** For some commands to work properly, your symbol path              ***
*** must point to .pdb files that have full type information.         ***
***                                                                   ***
*** Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not         ***
*** contain the required information. Contact the group that          ***
*** provided you with these symbols if you need this command to       ***
*** work.                                                             ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
```

How do I set up WinDbg to find the symbols?

<sub>Disclaimer: This is intended to be a canonical question to all the *wrong symbols* posts in [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg).</sub>

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Symbols can be set up correctly in various different ways.

*WARNING*: The examples here use `\\server\symbols` which is typically a network storage that is not available. Adapt it to your local server or leave that part out completely if you don't have one. A non-existent server may cause delays etc.

### TLDR version for 80% of the cases

Create a new folder `c:\symbols` for symbols provided by Microsoft. Then type

```
.symfix+ c:\symbols
.reload
```

(or `reload -f` if necessary)

Make sure you have an Internet connection, since this will contact some Microsoft servers and download symbols from there.

In 80+% of the cases, this might already solve your symbols problem. If not, read on.

### Fixing symbols by commands

WinDbg will look for symbols in the order they appear in the symbol path. Therefore it's a good idea to put your local symbols first, then some company local network share and then download symbols from the Internet and store a copy locally.

```
.sympath c:\mysymbols ; *** Symbols of your application, locally, flat list of PDB files
.sympath+ cache*c:\symbolcache ; *** (optional) Create a cache for everything
.sympath+ \\server\symbols ; *** Symbols provided from a network share
.symfix+ c:\symbols ; *** Microsoft symbols
```

### Fixing symbols by menu

In WinDbg (but not the command line equivalents) you can set a symbol path by `File/Symbol File Path...` or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. You enter it in the following format

```
c:\mysymbols;cache*c:\symbolcache;\\server\symbols;SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

### Fixing symbols by command line

WinDbg also takes the `-y` command line switch if you prefer having different desktop links with different symbol path setups.

```
WinDbg -y "<symbol path>"
```

Note that you need the complete path here, which is in a form like

```
c:\mysymbols;cache*c:\symbolcache;\\server\symbols;SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

### Fixing symbols by environment variable

There is a environment variable called `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` which can be set to a symbol path as well. Use the following syntax:

```
c:\mysymbols;cache*c:\symbolcache;\\server\symbols;SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Note that not only WinDbg evaluates this variable, but also Visual Studio, Process Explorer, Process Monitor and potentially other software. You may experience performance impact setting this environment variable.

### Saving the symbol path as part of a workspace

If you have a rather complex symbol setup which includes several paths, become familiar with the [concept of WinDbg workspaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg.aspx).

Workspaces allow you to save the symbol path so you don't have to re-type all the commands in every debugging session.

Once you're satisfied with the workspace, create a link for WinDbg to include `-Q` which means " Suppress the annoying "Save workspace?" question".

So far I'm very happy having save the symbols as part of the `Base` workspace.

### Deferred symbols

Deferred symbols (indicated as such during a `lm` command) are not a problem. WinDbg will load them whenever needed. To force loading all of them, type

```
ld*
```

### Debugging symbol issues

If the symbols (PDBs) do not work as expected, use the

```
!sym noisy
```

to get more information about what WinDbg is exactly doing when resolving symbols.

When you found the solution, turn it off with

```
!sym quiet
```

To check individual symbols for correctness, you can use the `symchk` tool which comes with WinDbg.

```
Symchk /if <exe> /s <symbol path> /av /od /pf
/if = input is a file
/s  = symbol file path
/od = all details
/av = verify
/pf = check if private symbols are available
```

or get [ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) which is a bit easier to use

```
ChkMatch -c <exe file> <pdb file>
```

If you have trouble accessing symbols from a network share, make sure you logged on to the network share before. AFAIR, WinDbg does not ask for credentials.

### Official documentation

[Use the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311503/en-us) (should [redirect here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311503/use-the-microsoft-symbol-server-to-obtain-debug-symbol-files) but redirection is currently broken)

[Symbol path for Windows debuggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829.aspx)

Comment: @Techrocket9: ok, I added that information as a warning in the beginning of the post

Comment: The link to the Microsoft symbol Server no longer appears to work

Comment: @higginse: yes, that's a redirection issue on Microsoft side. Here's the destination: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311503/use-the-microsoft-symbol-server-to-obtain-debug-symbol-files

Comment: Can anyone expand on _"You may experience performance impact setting [_NT_SYMBOL_PATH] environment variable."_ ? I can't find any information on what performance issues this would cause, and why.

Answer (score 9):

After opening the dump file, click File, select Symbol File Path or (Ctrl+S). This open box shows the default path set by environment the variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`.
In my case this shows:

```
SRV*C:\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

1. Insert your local symbols path before and ";" after any entry.
2. Select Reload box.
3. Click OK.
4. In the Command prompt run: `ld*`
5. wait for symbols to load.

Comment: This answer is too simple to be complete. It e.g. ignores the concept of workspaces and assumes you have _NT_SYMBOL_PATH set. If you open a dump file, it's possible that a workspace gets loaded, which has a completely different symbol path already.

Comment: This is the sequence I have successfully used and it works very well for me. I don't usually use workspaces.