# Analizing crash dump

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

I'm having an issue trying to find out to which problem is crash dump pointing. If someone could help me it would be nice.
This is what I get in windbg.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\MAJSTOR\Documents\Sports Interactive\Football Manager 2015\crash dumps\FM 2015 v15.3.2.627042 (2015.06.26 17.55.38).dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Fri Jun 26 17:55:38.000 2015 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:32.000
................................................................
.......................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1bac.ea8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not  available)
eax=76a80781 ebx=00000000 ecx=0a7ff803 edx=777970f4 esi=000002c4 edi=00000000
eip=777970f4 esp=0a7ff794 ebp=0a7ff800 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
777970f4 c3              ret
```

Comment: Fix up symbols, then type `!analyze` to get started with analysis. The symbols for Microsoft binaries could be setup using command `.sympath SRV*c:\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`. Add your own symbols for any private binaries required.

Comment: Football Manager 2015 looks like a game, so here you can't get symbols for and this make debugging nearly impossible. But try to setup the symbols correctly, maybe it helps a bit.

Comment: Switch to the exception record with `.ecxr` for starters - from there you can work your way through memory/stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up symbols in WinDbg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)