# Operation not supported by integrated managed debugging

Tags: debugging, windbg

I'm trying to debug a sample code written in C++.

I load it into WinDbg and type `uf main` which should dissasemble the main function, but I get the error

```
0:000> uf main
Operation not supported by integrated managed debugging.
 error at 'main'
```

`sos.dll` and `mscordacwks.dll` are loaded.
What can I do?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.windbg/r2BvUe2mLhs/SSf2RJTgVBcJ

Comment: I don't think C++ is considered managed code?

Comment: Why would you load sos.dll and mscordacwks.dll when it is not managed code?

Comment: I saw it suggested in several places, but didn't know what managed code was until after I'd loaded. Doesn't work either way.

Comment: There is one version of WinDbg (6.7.5.0) which has .NET support built-in. What's the version number of your WinDbg?

Comment: Also, have you set up WinDbg to find the [symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)? Please confirm that symbols are available by checking the output of the `lm`command.

Comment: 6.12.0002.633 is the version number. Output of lm: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Si9XyqKX

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you provide more detailed steps, e.g. how you loaded sos and mscordacwks? The error message though is still included in 6.12.2.633, so it might be possible to see it. It was removed in WinDbg 6.1.

Comment: I entered .load /path/to/sos.dll and .load /path/to/mscordacwks.dll. That's all. I also changed some settings in my compiler (Visual c++ 2008) to include debug symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled via VS command line. cl /Zi file.cpp
Worked like a charm :)