# VS2013 Crash After Pull with Git from command Line

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gitlab, pull

Hi to everybody and tks in advance for your help!

I have a web app in VS2013 working just fine, but everytime I make a pull from my gitlab repository, then I can't open the solution anymore. The only workaround I have found is to delete the repository and clone it from scratch. I tried the most popular solution on google (like running git gc before pulling) but I can't fix it.

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 12.0.31101.0
  Problem Signature 03: 54548724
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.34209
  Problem Signature 06: 534894cc
  Problem Signature 07: 254
  Problem Signature 08: 10
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    3082
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Can please somebody help me with this?
Tks a lot!!

Comment: create a dump of VS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), open it in Windbg and run **!analyze -v** What do you see?

Comment: I see a lot of things, but I can't understand a thing! At the end of the result of the analysis said: 
STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb
SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1
SYMBOL_NAME:  clr!CopyPDBs+15478
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll
BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_e0434352_clr.dll!
CopyPDBs
WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  
http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/devenv_exe/12_0_31101
_0/54548724/KERNELBASE_dll/6_1_7601_18869/556363bc/e043435
2/0000c42d.htm?Retriage=1
Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: post the complete output of windbg here or upload it to pastebin

Comment: As a workaround, perhaps you could try to use a better git gui than visual studio : gitextensions or sourcetree...

Comment: Here is the complete output: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=xaBVHn6E

Comment: Phillippe: I don't use visual studio as git gui, I use Git Preview and use the command line. Tks.

Comment: you have to fix the debug symbols: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046

Comment: have you fixed the symbols in windbg? Please post the new output.

Comment: Not yet, but I'll do it in a couple of hours. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem. It's seem that there was a file in git (a css file) that was causing VS to crash. When I did a pull having the file in my local GIT, that file was overwritten and the problems starts. But if I delete all my local GIT and do a new clone from Git Repository, all seems to work just fine. To fix it, I delete the file from master git and upload it again from scratch... I couldn't figure it out what was the problem with the css file, maybe it was corrupted in the master or something like this.
Thanks to all for your help.
Best Regards!