# Visual Studio crashes when creating Team Project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Visual Studio crashes and restarts when I try to create a new Team Project in TFS.

[image: http://s24.postimg.org/php1p3ml0/crash.jpg]

I've removed Visual Studio and reinstalled it again but the problem still appears.

Comment: do you get any error messages when VS crashes? Is there anything in the event log? What version of VS, what version of TFS?

Comment: VS 2013 please see this photo http://s24.postimg.org/php1p3ml0/crash.jpg

Comment: Is there anything in the event log, either on the server or on your PC? What version of TFS? What version of Visual Studio? You need to provide as much diagnostic information as possible.

Comment: capture a crash dump (Procdump: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx or WER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the crashing Visual studio. Open it in windbg, fix the debug symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) run **!analyze -v** and post the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing visual studio team explorer update 5 RC will solve this problem