# Deadlock or waiting in a loop?

Tags: c#, c, c++-cli, deadlock, windbg

Folks,

I am trying to track why my application stops responding to events.

Some Background:
The App in question My_C_Application is a (C application with both C and C++ code) it also referenced a .Net dll which exposes functionality as COM objects,
these are register using regasm and the associated tlh is used to resolve these classes to load and use. The app also uses a third party Messaging library
IPWorks, we use the SSL version for c++ here and this talks to other systems which are .net based over IP. These other systems use the .Net version of IpWorks, 
My_C_Application acts as the business logic engine and the other apps handle Data, GUI etc.

This all seems to work fine in testing & in many client sites, in some client sites we are getting reports where the GUI is not responding to an clicks (now we have seen this
occur on site, the GUI is hanndling the Key Presses and dispatches its messages approiately) It seems My_C_Application is not handling/ receiving the events.

We caught this issue and using procdump -mp we got a dump to analyze.

I automate this for Crashes with our own application which calls out to the console version of windbg, we execute the following commands for a crash :

!analyze -v; .ecxr;

Now i understand this will be of no use for a hang, so i execute additional commands after this has setup the symbol paths for me etc.

```
    Opened log file 'C:\crash\AutomateCrashAnalysis\AutomateCrashAnalysis\bin\Debug\CrashSummary1584124051.txt'

    Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


    Loading Dump File [C:\Crash\My_C_Application.exe_150804_094908.dmp\My_C_Application.exe_150804_094908.dmp]
    User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

    Comment: '
    *** procdump.exe -mp 7908
    *** Manual dump'
    Symbol search path is: C:\crash\AutomateCrashAnalysis\AutomateCrashAnalysis\bin\Debug\My_C_Application___Win32_Debug;srv*C:\SYMBOLS*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
    Executable search path is: C:\crash\AutomateCrashAnalysis\AutomateCrashAnalysis\bin\Debug\My_C_Application___Win32_Debug
    Windows XP Version 2600 (Service Pack 3) UP Free x86 compatible
    Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
    Machine Name:
    Debug session time: Tue Aug  4 09:49:13.000 2015 (UTC + 1:00)
    System Uptime: 0 days 14:59:40.140
    Process Uptime: 0 days 3:08:03.000
    ................................................................
    .....................
    eax=00000000 ebx=00128094 ecx=0012804c edx=7c90e514 esi=00000000 edi=7ffd5000
    eip=7c90e514 esp=0012806c ebp=00128108 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
    cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00200246
    ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
    7c90e514 c3              ret
    0:000> !analyze -v; .ecxr;
    *******************************************************************************
    *                                                                             *
    *                        Exception Analysis                                   *
    *                                                                             *
    *******************************************************************************

    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
    Unable to load image C:\EPOS\ipworksssl9.dll, Win32 error 0n2
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ipworksssl9.dll - 
    Unable to load image C:\AppPath\My_C_Application.exe, Win32 error 0n2
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for My_C_Application.exe
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for My_C_Application.exe - 
    *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for xpsp2res.dll
    GetPageUrlData failed, server returned HTTP status 404
    URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/My_C_Application_exe/0_0_0_0/unknown/0_0_0_0/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

    FAULTING_IP: 
    +1562faf0007da9c
    00000000 ??              ???

    EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
    .exr 0xffffffffffffffff
    ExceptionAddress: 00000000
       ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
      ExceptionFlags: 00000000
    NumberParameters: 0

    FAULTING_THREAD:  000020f8

    PROCESS_NAME:  My_C_Application.exe

    ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

    EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

    MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

    NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

    APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

    MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
    !dumpstack -EE
    No export dumpstack found

    LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7c90df4a to 7c90e514

    ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE

    PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STACKIMMUNE

    BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NOSOS_WRONG_SYMBOLS

    STACK_TEXT:  
    00000000 00000000 My_C_Application.exe+0x0


    STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 00000000 ; kb ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

    SYMBOL_NAME:  My_C_Application.exe

    FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

    MODULE_NAME: My_C_Application

    IMAGE_NAME:  My_C_Application.exe

    DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  55b8bb1c

    FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE_80000003_My_C_Application.exe!Unknown

    BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NOSOS_WRONG_SYMBOLS_My_C_Application.exe

    FOLLOWUP_IP: 
    My_C_Application+0
    00400000 4d              dec     ebp

    WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/My_C_Application_exe/0_0_0_0/55b8bb1c/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/80000003/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

    Followup: MachineOwner
    ---------

    Minidump doesn't have an exception context
    Unable to get exception context, HRESULT 0x80004002
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    0:000> .lastevent
    Last event: 1ee4.20f8: Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first/second chance not available)
      debugger time: Tue Aug  4 12:40:51.455 2015 (UTC + 1:00)
```

Is there anything of use in the above output that i can use?

Now the code we have is the exact code that is running on site, the EXE was however re-built on another PC for debuging so the symbols dont seem to load,
we have seen this before so we execute the following commands:

```
    0:000> .symopt+0x80000000
    Symbol options are 0x800B0277:
      0x00000001 - SYMOPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE
      0x00000002 - SYMOPT_UNDNAME
      0x00000004 - SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS
      0x00000010 - SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES
      0x00000020 - SYMOPT_OMAP_FIND_NEAREST
      0x00000040 - SYMOPT_LOAD_ANYTHING
      0x00000200 - SYMOPT_FAIL_CRITICAL_ERRORS
      0x00010000 - SYMOPT_AUTO_PUBLICS
      0x00020000 - SYMOPT_NO_IMAGE_SEARCH
      0x00080000 - SYMOPT_NO_PROMPTS
      0x80000000 - SYMOPT_DEBUG
    0:000> .reload -f -i My_C_Application.exe=00400000
    DBGHELP: C:\crash\AutomateCrashAnalysis\AutomateCrashAnalysis\bin\Debug\My_C_Application___Win32_Debug\My_C_Application.exe - OK
    DBGENG:  C:\crash\AutomateCrashAnalysis\AutomateCrashAnalysis\bin\Debug\My_C_Application___Win32_Debug\My_C_Application.exe - Mapped image memory
    DBGHELP: My_C_Application - private symbols & lines 
             c:\crash\automatecrashanalysis\automatecrashanalysis\bin\debug\My_C_Application___win32_debug\My_C_Application.pdb
    0:000> lme
    start    end        module name
    00400000 013ec000   My_C_Application C (private pdb symbols)  c:\crash\automatecrashanalysis\automatecrashanalysis\bin\debug\My_C_Application___win32_debug\My_C_Application.pdb
    790c0000 79bba000   mscorlib_ni C (deferred)             
    7a440000 7abdf000   System_ni C (deferred)             
    7afd0000 7bbaf000   System_Windows_Forms_ni C (deferred)
```

Now we should have the symbols loaded correctly, if i execute kv we see the following:

```
    0:000> kv
    ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
    00128068 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 00128094 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
    0012806c 7c809590 00000002 00128094 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
    00128108 7e4195f9 00000002 00128130 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    00128164 7752e78e 00000001 00128464 000003e8 user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    0012818c 775572af 00128464 000003e8 001281b8 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x80 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    00128200 79fd05fd 00000002 000003e8 00000001 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcf (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    00128220 79fd0564 00000000 000003e8 00000001 mscorwks!NT5WaitRoutine+0x51 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    0012828c 79fd04c8 00000001 00128464 00000000 mscorwks!MsgWaitHelper+0xa5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    001282ac 79f6915d 00000001 00128464 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x28 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    00128330 79f691f2 00000001 00128464 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    00128380 79f99d40 00000001 00128464 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    00128484 792b698f 00000000 00000000 03d5bbec mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    001284a0 792b6945 000003e8 00000000 79317b08 mscorlib_ni+0x1f698f
    001284b8 7b6f218f 00000000 00000103 0000c121 mscorlib_ni+0x1f6945
    001284d0 7ba2e34b a92aae2d 79e749d8 00128668 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x72218f
    00128564 7b6f3aec 00000001 03d5bbd8 03d5bbb8 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0xa5e34b
    001285a0 7b921b1b 03d5bbd8 03d5bbd8 03d5bbb8 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x723aec
    001285b8 7a932cb6 03d5ac5c 03c2d938 00000001 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x951b1b
    001285ec 7a930e6f 03d5ac5c ffffffff 00000000 System_ni+0x4f2cb6
    00128638 7a93205f 03d5ac5c 00000009 00000000 System_ni+0x4f0e6f
    00128654 7aaa767a 001fab80 00000001 a92aae2d System_ni+0x4f205f
    001286e4 7e418734 000c00be 0000201a 00000001 System_ni+0x66767a
    00128710 7e418816 030b7392 000c00be 0000201a user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
    00128778 7e4189cd 00000000 030b7392 000c00be user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    001287d8 7e4196c7 00128800 00000001 0012881c user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x306 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    001287e8 1001d222 00128800 00000000 00165008 user32!DispatchMessageA+0xf (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    0012881c 1007f803 00000014 00040232 100a1e04 ipworksssl9+0x1d222
    001288f4 009d259f 00128924 00e238ae 00000000 ipworksssl9+0x7f803
    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 My_C_Application!sprintf+0x9f (CONV: cdecl) [sprintf.c @ 104]
```

Does WaitForMultipleObjects indicate a deadlock (waiting for a Lock/CriticalSection/Mutex) ??

I was expecting to see a while loop locked up in My_C_Application but i dont, i ran ~* kp but none of these threads appear to be looping or locked in My_C_Application.

```
    :000> ~* kp

    .  0  Id: 1ee4.20f8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    00128068 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0012806c 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    00128108 7e4195f9 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    00128164 7752e78e user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e
    0012818c 775572af ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x80
    00128200 79fd05fd ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcf
    00128220 79fd0564 mscorwks!NT5WaitRoutine+0x51
    0012828c 79fd04c8 mscorwks!MsgWaitHelper+0xa5
    001282ac 79f6915d mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x28
    00128330 79f691f2 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c
    00128380 79f99d40 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
    00128484 792b698f mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156
    001284a0 792b6945 mscorlib_ni+0x1f698f
    001284b8 7b6f218f mscorlib_ni+0x1f6945
    001284d0 7ba2e34b System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x72218f
    00128564 7b6f3aec System_Windows_Forms_ni+0xa5e34b
    001285a0 7b921b1b System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x723aec
    001285b8 7a932cb6 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x951b1b
    001285ec 7a930e6f System_ni+0x4f2cb6
    00128638 7a93205f System_ni+0x4f0e6f
    00128654 7aaa767a System_ni+0x4f205f
    001286e4 7e418734 System_ni+0x66767a
    00128710 7e418816 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
    00128778 7e4189cd user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
    001287d8 7e4196c7 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x306
    001287e8 1001d222 user32!DispatchMessageA+0xf
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    0012881c 1007f803 ipworksssl9+0x1d222
    001288f4 009d259f ipworksssl9+0x7f803
    00000000 00000000 My_C_Application!sprintf(char * string = <Memory access error>, char * format = <Memory access error>)+0x9f [sprintf.c @ 104]

       1  Id: 1ee4.2364 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    01edfe64 7e4191be ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    01edfe8c 00986a0f user32!NtUserGetMessage+0xc
    01edff80 009867d8 My_C_Application!WMConnection::threadFunc(void)+0x20a [C:\Code\BuildFolder\My_C_Application\SourcePath\WMConnection.cpp @ 139]
    01edffb4 7c80b729 My_C_Application!wmConnectionThreadFunc(void * lpData = 0x01d5b970)+0x62 [C:\Code\BuildFolder\My_C_Application\SourcePath\WMConnection.cpp @ 80]
    01edffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       2  Id: 1ee4.204c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdc000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0214fecc 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0214fed0 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    0214ff6c 7c80a115 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    0214ff88 72d2312a kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
    0214ffb4 7c80b729 wdmaud!MixerCallbackThread+0x42
    0214ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       3  Id: 1ee4.210c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdb000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0224fd84 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0224fd88 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    0224fe24 7c80a115 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    0224fe40 73f114a2 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
    0224fe58 73f12862 dsound!WaitObjectArray+0x17
    0224ff78 73f198df dsound!CThread::TpWaitObjectArray+0x51
    0224ff98 73f12896 dsound!CCallbackEventPool::ThreadProc+0x1a
    0224ffa4 73f1b2e9 dsound!CThread::ThreadLoop+0x1d
    0224ffac 73f1b2ae dsound!CThread::PrivateThreadProc+0x32
    0224ffb4 7c80b729 dsound!CThread::ThreadStartRoutine+0xd
    0224ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       4  Id: 1ee4.2344 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffda000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0244fd8c 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0244fd90 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    0244fe2c 7c80a115 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    0244fe48 73f114a2 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
    0244fe60 73f12862 dsound!WaitObjectArray+0x17
    0244ff80 73f1292b dsound!CThread::TpWaitObjectArray+0x51
    0244ff98 73f12896 dsound!CDirectSoundAdministrator::ThreadProc+0x16
    0244ffa4 73f1b2e9 dsound!CThread::ThreadLoop+0x1d
    0244ffac 73f1b2ae dsound!CThread::PrivateThreadProc+0x32
    0244ffb4 7c80b729 dsound!CThread::ThreadStartRoutine+0xd
    0244ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       5  Id: 1ee4.22d8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd9000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0256ff08 7c90df5a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0256ff0c 7c8025db ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    0256ff70 7c802542 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8
    0256ff84 5c57ae32 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    0256ffac 5c57bec0 dmime!CPerformance::Realtime+0x127
    0256ffb4 7c80b729 dmime!CPerformance::Release+0x94
    0256ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       6  Id: 1ee4.2190 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd8000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0266feec 7c90df5a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0266fef0 7c8025db ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    0266ff54 7c802542 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8
    0266ff68 5c57effc kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    0266ffac 5c57f04d dmime!CPerformance::Transport+0x47d
    0266ffb4 7c80b729 dmime!CPerformance::Transport+0x4ce
    0266ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       7  Id: 1ee4.1dfc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd7000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    029dff10 7c90df5a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    029dff14 7c8025db ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    029dff78 7c802542 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8
    029dff8c 6c9ae4b5 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    029dffac 6c9ae4ed dmsynth!CDSLinkList::SynthProc+0x95
    029dffb4 7c80b729 dmsynth!CDSLinkList::SynthProc+0xcd
    029dffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       8  Id: 1ee4.2778 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd6000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    02adff78 7c90da4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    02adff7c 71a5d320 ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xc
    02adffb4 7c80b729 mswsock!SockAsyncThread+0x5a
    02adffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

       9  Id: 1ee4.2188 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd4000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    02eafce8 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    02eafcec 7c92a51a ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    02eaffb4 7c80b729 ntdll!RtlpWaitThread+0x13d
    02eaffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      10  Id: 1ee4.ee0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffaf000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    02fafec8 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    02fafecc 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    02faff68 7c80a115 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    02faff84 769c87bd kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
    02faffb4 7c80b729 userenv!NotificationThread+0x5f
    02faffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      11  Id: 1ee4.26b4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffae000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0333fe38 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0333fe3c 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    0333fed8 7c80a115 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    0333fef4 79f86a21 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
    0333ff54 79f8697e mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+0xe9
    0333ff84 79f868a5 mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+0xe5
    0333ffb4 7c80b729 mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+0x9c
    0333ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      12  Id: 1ee4.bc8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffad000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    034ffcd0 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    034ffcd4 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    034ffd70 7c80a115 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    034ffd8c 79fc5107 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
    034ffdac 79fc9568 mscorwks!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x77
    034ffdc0 79e9b08f mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x49
    034ffdd4 79e9b02b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
    034ffe68 79e9af51 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
    034ffea4 79f73514 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
    034ffecc 79f73525 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32
    034ffedc 79fc019c mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd
    034fff14 79fc4551 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb
    034fffb4 7c80b729 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
    034fffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      13  Id: 1ee4.23b8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffaa000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    03abfee4 7c90df5a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    03abfee8 7c8025db ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    03abff4c 7c802542 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8
    03abff60 009a6408 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    03abff7c 009dc2d7 My_C_Application!file4writeDelayMain+0x38
    03abffb4 7c80b729 My_C_Application!_threadstart(void * ptd = 0x01d5fa50)+0xa7 [thread.c @ 187]
    03abffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      14  Id: 1ee4.fa8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa9000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    05c6fee4 7c90df5a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    05c6fee8 7c8025db ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    05c6ff4c 7c802542 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8
    05c6ff60 009a8128 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    05c6ff7c 009dc2d7 My_C_Application!file4advanceReadMain+0x38
    05c6ffb4 7c80b729 My_C_Application!_threadstart(void * ptd = 0x01d5faf8)+0xa7 [thread.c @ 187]
    05c6ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      15  Id: 1ee4.b0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa8000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    05d6fed4 7c90df5a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    05d6fed8 7c8025db ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    05d6ff3c 7c802542 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8
    05d6ff50 77596f14 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    05d6ff6c 77567135 ole32!CDllHost::MTAWorkerLoop+0x2b
    05d6ff8c 775263f4 ole32!CDllHost::WorkerThread+0xc1
    05d6ff94 774fe4ba ole32!DLLHostThreadEntry+0xd
    05d6ffa8 774fe522 ole32!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x1e
    05d6ffb4 7c80b729 ole32!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x1b
    05d6ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      16  Id: 1ee4.232c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa5000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0df8fa74 7c90d21a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0df8fa78 7c8023f1 ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc
    0df8fad0 7c802455 kernel32!SleepEx+0x61
    0df8fae0 005594cf kernel32!Sleep+0xf
    0df8ff7c 009dc2d7 My_C_Application!Read_FPs_Thread(void * pvoid = 0x00ecb058)+0x888 [C:\Code\BuildFolder\My_C_Application\SourcePath\cbe_pump.cpp @ 2085]
    0df8ffb4 7c80b729 My_C_Application!_threadstart(void * ptd = 0x02fc6018)+0xa7 [thread.c @ 187]
    0df8ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      17  Id: 1ee4.2590 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa7000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    05e6fe14 7c90daaa ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    05e6fe18 77e765e3 ntdll!NtReplyWaitReceivePortEx+0xc
    05e6ff80 77e76caf rpcrt4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ReceiveLotsaCalls+0x12a
    05e6ff88 77e76ad1 rpcrt4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd
    05e6ffa8 77e76c97 rpcrt4!BaseCachedThreadRoutine+0x79
    05e6ffb4 7c80b729 rpcrt4!ThreadStartRoutine+0x1a
    05e6ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      18  Id: 1ee4.1b54 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa6000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0e22fe50 7c90df4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0e22fe54 7c809590 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
    0e22fef0 7e4195f9 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
    0e22ff4c 7e4196a8 user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e
    0e22ff68 4ec674b2 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+0x1f
    0e22ffb4 7c80b729 GdiPlus!BackgroundThreadProc+0x59
    0e22ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      19  Id: 1ee4.23bc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa4000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0e84f6d8 7c90d21a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0e84f6dc 7c8023f1 ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc
    0e84f734 79e889d8 kernel32!SleepEx+0x61
    0e84f768 79f0e0b8 mscorwks!EESleepEx+0xbb
    0e84f778 79f0e0a6 mscorwks!CExecutionEngine::ClrSleepEx+0xe
    0e84f78c 79f0e065 mscorwks!ClrSleepEx+0x14
    0e84f7c8 79f0e166 mscorwks!Thread::UserSleep+0x63
    0e84f868 0e3af62b mscorwks!ThreadNative::Sleep+0xce
    WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
    0e84f8b8 792d7026 0xe3af62b
    0e84f8c4 792e04af mscorlib_ni+0x217026
    0e84f8d8 792d6fa4 mscorlib_ni+0x2204af
    0e84f8f0 79e71b4c mscorlib_ni+0x216fa4
    0e84f900 79e88e45 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
    0e84f980 79e96461 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
    0e84fab8 79e96494 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c
    0e84fad4 79e964b2 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f
    0e84faec 79f0f9b7 mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::CallWithValueTypes_RetArgSlot+0x1a
    0e84fcd4 79e9b08f mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker+0x192
    0e84fce8 79e9b02b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
    0e84fd7c 79e9af51 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
    0e84fdb8 79e9b0dd mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
    0e84fde0 79f0f788 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x33e
    0e84fdf8 79f0f862 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::KickOff+0x13
    0e84fe94 79fc4551 mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread+0x269
    0e84ffb4 7c80b729 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
    0e84ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      20  Id: 1ee4.27c8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa2000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0eb0fed0 7c90d21a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0eb0fed4 7c8023f1 ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc
    0eb0ff2c 79ee7c61 kernel32!SleepEx+0x61
    0eb0ffa8 79ee7b0f mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire+0x6d
    0eb0ffb4 7c80b729 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart+0x57
    0eb0ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      21  Id: 1ee4.2710 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffa1000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    0e5cff10 7e4191be ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    0e5cff30 7752ffc6 user32!NtUserGetMessage+0xc
    0e5cff70 775264c1 ole32!CDllHost::STAWorkerLoop+0x72
    0e5cff8c 775263f4 ole32!CDllHost::WorkerThread+0xc8
    0e5cff94 774fe4ba ole32!DLLHostThreadEntry+0xd
    0e5cffa8 774fe522 ole32!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x1e
    0e5cffb4 7c80b729 ole32!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x1b
    0e5cffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37

      22  Id: 1ee4.2530 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    01c4fd74 7c90da4a ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
    01c4fd78 7c80a7e6 ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xc
    01c4fda4 79f65810 kernel32!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+0x29
    01c4fe14 79fc4551 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+0x141
    01c4ffb4 7c80b729 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
    01c4ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37
```

Is there any other commands i can run to figure out where this Lock/Loop is called from in My_C_Application??

Additions:

As requested by  EdChum, it would appear from this we are not waiting on any Locks

```
    0:000> !cs -s -l -o
    -----------------------------------------
    DebugInfo          = 0x0016eea8
    Critical section   = 0x01d59c60 (+0x1D59C60)
    LOCKED
    LockCount          = 0x0
    OwningThread       = 0x000020f8
    RecursionCount     = 0x1
    LockSemaphore      = 0x0
    SpinCount          = 0x00000000
    OwningThread DbgId = ~0s
    OwningThread Stack =
        ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
        00128068 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 00128094 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
        0012806c 7c809590 00000002 00128094 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
        00128108 7e4195f9 00000002 00128130 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        00128164 7752e78e 00000001 00128464 000003e8 user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        0012818c 775572af 00128464 000003e8 001281b8 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x80 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        00128200 79fd05fd 00000002 000003e8 00000001 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcf (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        00128220 79fd0564 00000000 000003e8 00000001 mscorwks!NT5WaitRoutine+0x51 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        0012828c 79fd04c8 00000001 00128464 00000000 mscorwks!MsgWaitHelper+0xa5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        001282ac 79f6915d 00000001 00128464 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x28 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        00128330 79f691f2 00000001 00128464 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        00128380 79f99d40 00000001 00128464 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        00128484 792b698f 00000000 00000000 03d5bbec mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        001284a0 792b6945 000003e8 00000000 79317b08 mscorlib_ni+0x1f698f
        001284b8 7b6f218f 00000000 00000103 0000c121 mscorlib_ni+0x1f6945
        001284d0 7ba2e34b a92aae2d 79e749d8 00128668 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x72218f
        00128564 7b6f3aec 00000001 03d5bbd8 03d5bbb8 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0xa5e34b
        001285a0 7b921b1b 03d5bbd8 03d5bbd8 03d5bbb8 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x723aec
        001285b8 7a932cb6 03d5ac5c 03c2d938 00000001 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x951b1b
        001285ec 7a930e6f 03d5ac5c ffffffff 00000000 System_ni+0x4f2cb6
        00128638 7a93205f 03d5ac5c 00000009 00000000 System_ni+0x4f0e6f
    ntdll!RtlpStackTraceDataBase is NULL. Probably the stack traces are not enabled.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post the output from `!cs -s -l -o`

Comment: Hi EdChum, I have updated the original post to include the output requested.

Comment: I only see a single critical section that is in a locked state so it's unlikely to be a deadlock based on the output

Comment: Ok thanks, so my other thought is we are locked in a loop waiting for something, i thought one of the threads in the dump would be a call stack that i could trace all the way back into my code but none appear to be, anything else i could try with the dumpfile to figure this out? Thanks

Comment: I'd look at the logic for that call stack for that thread, it's possible it's waiting for an even that is never signalled

Comment: The problem is none of the code listed in that call stack looks familiar to any code we have in the App

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if,, when compiling/linking of all the associated source code, that the -g parameter be used (or for gcc the 'ggdb' parameter .  This will make the executables much larger, but the info would contain line numbers rather than global symbol+offset

Comment: I hear ya, but we cant get an update to this site at the moment

Comment: This is .NET related. Did you [fix the symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)? Can you load the SOS extension? What does [tag:sosex] `!dlk` say? Windows XP, do you still support that? There are newer [versions of WinDbg](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/) available.

Comment: `!analyze` also has a `-hang` switch. Try it. Why did you use `procdump -mp` and not `-ma`? `-mp` may remove information which is important for .NET analysis. Other than that, it doesn't look right that `My_C_Application!sprintf()` does some SSL communication. Are you sure you really built the exact version of your application as shipped to the customer? Installing updates to the build server (new compiler version etc.) may cause completely misleading callstacks.

Comment: This is a managed application, so you should post the output of SOS's `!clrstack` for all the managed threads.

Answer (score 0):

From what you show, it looks like you are deadlocking your message loop.

First thing to recognize, when you see frames like this:

```
mscorlib_ni+0x1f698f
mscorlib_ni+0x1f6945
System_ni+0x4f2cb6
```

That is jitted managed code from your application, you won't have normal symbols for it because the code gets built and placed there at run-time. You can use `!ip2md mscorlib_ni+0x1f698f` (once [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) is loaded) to see the managed function name. Looking at the jitted frames will help with the "I don't see any of my code running" (it is, it just isn't obvious).

Looking at this stack, the things that pop out to me is the call to [DispatchMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934.aspx)() which is used in a standard message loop, it then calls into your application code (totally expected) to handle the messages, but then there is a [WaitOne](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone.aspx) called. You will need to inspect your code to see what event you are waiting on. Most likely it is waiting on something that can't be signaled if other messages cannot be processed.

```
mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
mscorlib_ni+0x1f698f <<<<<< look here
... jitted app code ...
user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x306 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
user32!DispatchMessageA+0xf (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
...
```