# What is INT 0x29 (29h, 41) on Windows x86-64?

Tags: windows, x86, x86-64, interrupt

What does this x86-64 assembly code do? What is interrupt 41?

```
MOV ECX, 0x7
INT 0x29
```

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail?view=msvc-170 says:

> Internally, `__fastfail` is implemented by using several architecture-specific mechanisms:
>
> | Architecture | Instruction | Location of code argument |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | x86 | int 0x29 | ecx |
> | x64 | int 0x29 | rcx |
> | ARM | Opcode 0xDEFB | r0 |
> | ARM64 | Opcode 0xF003 | x0 |

https://www.softwareverify.com/blog/fail-fast-codes/ says that 7 is `FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT`.

Related: [Find out what's calling __fastfail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383972/find-out-whats-calling-fastfail)