# Visual Studio 2015 hangs during file operations

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Approx. once or twice a day, after working for several hours with an instance of Visual Studio 2015, the application hangs when performing a file operation (like rename or delete).

This well-known message appears:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is busy…

Then only solution I found so far is to kill the process via Task Manager.

When starting Visual Studio again, In most of the cases the file operation *was* actually performed before the hang.

For the next few hours, all file operations work again.

**My question**

Any idea on how to narrow this down and ideally solve it?

**Extensions**

Some of the extensions I've installed are:

- ReSharper 9
- Visual SVN
- Web Essentials 2015

**Too broad**

I've found similar questions ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498175/visual-studio-is-busy)) for previous versions of Visual Studio that were closed as *too broad*.

I've decided to still ask my question since I've found no questions specific to the 2015 version. Maybe there are better ways to find the reason for the behaviour in this version?

Comment: One possiblility is a ReSharper memory leak.  Try enabling monitoring of memory usage for ReSharper.  ReSharper -> Options -> Environment (General) -> Check "Show managed memory usage in status bar".  Now the memory usage will display in the bottom right hand corner of Visual Studio.  More importantly, you can actually right click on it and select "Collect Garbage" to free up some of that memory.

Comment: Install this update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3093266 which includes a GC fix

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm on the "Fast Ring". So I've already got that update.

Comment: try the R#10 EAP and look if this makes VS faster. If this also doesn't help, create a dump (process explorer) of the hanging devenv.exe, open it in Windbg, fix symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046), and run **!analyze -v -hang** or load the dmp in DebugDiag Analyzer. Does this show you where VS hangs?

Comment: an update on this? Have you looked at the hang dump?

Comment: where able to solve it?

Comment: have you captured a dump during the freeze? have you analyzed the dump?

Comment: have you tried the RC of the update 1 for VS2015?

Comment: the tech support from ms said it should be fixed in  RTM Update 1 VS2015. Its because this bug:https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/6154

Comment: Have you tried the VS2015 Update 1? Was this issues solved?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Just downloading from [this URL](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx). Thanks for your info!

Comment: have you finished installation of the update1? does it fix your issue or not?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll have to wait a few days to see whether it still occurs or not.

Comment: Just stepped into another hang. So my conclusion ist: Update 1 did _not_ fix this for me.

Comment: contact the Microsoft support for an more detailed help

Comment: Same issue here. Any luck solving it?

Comment: This is  really annoying issue. I do NOT have Resharper or Visual SVN or Web Essentials. Its not an extension issue I think.

Comment: Good question but no answer.

Comment: I've had this same issue with no fancy extensions beyond the python stuff.

Comment: I disabled reshaper with Tools -> Options -> Reshaper Ultimate -> General -> Disable (while moving around files - It seemed to help greatly!) Was previously talking 15s+ to move a file. I then reabled reshaper and tried to move a file. Again it is taking 15s+

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issues over many years on my home laptop, which is pretty old and under-powered.

In the office on several different much more powerfull PCs, whilst working on the same solution with the same version of VS the problem rarely happens. I'm consistently performing the same actions at home and at work.

There's no additional s/w running on my laptop, in fact I even disabled most VS extensions, and my AV software, to no avail.

Whilst hardly a scientific answer, I am convinced my issues are simply caused by a well under-powered machine, which I've been too lazy to upgrade given I've got access to powerful machines in my day job.

So if your machine isn't an especially high spec one, I'd suggest trying one that is, if for no other reason than ruling that out.

Comment: I think there are multiple sources of this problem. This just started occurring for me on a PC which for years never before had the issue.

Answer (score 2):

*If* you are using Reshaper and moving files is taking a long time.

Do this before you move a file:

Tools → Options → Reshaper Ultimate → General → Suspend Now

I assign the Reshaper_ToggleSuspended to keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to allow quick Suspending + Resuming.

Then resume after you are done to get the nice Reshaper features back...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a WPF project, it might also be a problem with one of the XDesProc processes.  When this happens to me, I kill all of those processes, and that unlocks things.