# How can I diagnose VS 2015 crash

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

When I drag over an object from my Data Sources window to an empty WinForm I get “Visual Studio 2015 has stopped Working” and it restarts. If I try and click on the triangle to expand that node it also crashes. (Vs 2015 update 1)

However, If I open that same project in VS 2013 everything works as expected. (Vs 2013 update 5)

**UPDATE 1:**

All Extensions like ReSharper and GostDoc I run in both environments.

**UPDATE 2:**

Windbg Output:

http://pastebin.com/hp7K7iZG

Comment: capture a crash dump (http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57), open it with Windbg (part of Debugging Tools/Windows SDK), inside windbg configure the symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run **!analyze -v**. Post what you see in the output.

Comment: Attach windbg to the devenv.exe process

Comment: Output is in link in Update 2, @magicandre1981

Comment: you get a stackoverflow. disable some extensions, and if you still get crashes, report this on connect: connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/