# Is the documentation for WinDbg SRV* wrong?

Tags: c++, windbg

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> If you include the string srv* in your symbol path, the debugger uses
>   a symbol server to get symbols from the default symbol store. For
>   example, the following command tells the debugger to use a symbol
>   server to get symbols from the default symbol store. **These symbols are
>   not cached on the local computer**.
>
> .sympath srv*

However what I found is the symbols **are** cached.

I am using WinDbg 10 and the default cache files seem to be created at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym` When I delete them and run an executable with path set to `srv*` the symbols are downloaded here.

So is the documentation wrong?

Comment: At least your interpretation has been proved wrong by you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is wrong (at least for WinDbg 6.2.9200.16384).

You can prove it by entering the mentioned command:

```
0:000> .sympath srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

So, as we can see from the output of WinDbg, the expanded symbol path (which will actually be used) contains `cache*` which indicates that symbols will be cached.

You found this in the [documentation for WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx), which might not be the correct place to define the behavior, since WinDbg does not load the symbols itself. Instead it uses the [dbghelp.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679294(v=vs.85).aspx) and the behavior of that DLL might change without the WinDbg help being updated.

---

The symbol path syntax is really hard to get used to and the documentation is spread all over the place. All the magic with expansion and default directories makes it even worse.

The flow is more or less:

1. Split the symbol path at ";" into array *elements*.
2. For each *element* in *elements*:

   1. Switch according to the beginning of the *element*:

      1. "cache*":

         1. Determine cache path:

            1. If there's a path after the asterisk use that path.

               Otherwise use the default cache path.
            2. Cache symbol from all the following *element*s in this path.
      2. "symsrv*":

         1. Split *element* at "*" into (mostly path) components.
         2. The first component is the symbol server DLL to use.
         3. The next components are paths. For each *path*:

            1. Look for symbol in *path*. The path can be one of

               - Local directory.
               - UNC.
               - HTTP or HTTPS URL - **has to be the last path**.
               - Empty string - means the default symbol store. (See [SymSetHomeDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681365(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`!homedir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563205(v=vs.85).aspx).)
            2. If found:

               1. Copy symbol to **all** the previous *path*s in this *element*.
               2. Finish symbol search
      3. "srv*":

         - Same as "symsrv*symsrv.dll*".
      4. Otherwise:

         1. Treat the *element* as path and look for the symbol there. (Without the hash etc. like done by symsrv.dll.)

Comment: makes sense, even this message `DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` also shows `cache` but what is expanded path really? so `srv*` is sort of a special path symbol itself?

Comment: Totally agree with `symbol path syntax is really hard to get used to`, it is very confusing and has too many meanings and variations.

Comment: You can have more there 3 items separated by asterisks. For example, my symbol path contains (among other things): `SRV*D:\Symbols\Microsoft\*\\smb\PublicSymbols\Microsoft\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;SRV*D:\Symbols\Chromium\*\\smb\PublicSymbols\Chromium\*https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com;` because I think that it's wasteful for every team member to download an 800MB PDB just for himself instead of sharing it. Another (esoteric) reason is if you use a custom symsrv DLL.

Comment: @conio: thanks. I was planning to have a generic question about the symbol path syntax and later refer to it. With your edit, that's probably not necessary any more (except maybe for Google reasons). Setting up symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg) is one part, but interpreting a symbol path is perhaps still worth its own question. Some examples like yours should be included.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: There's still a lot not covered here. For example that when searching "Standard Path Elements" (non-symbol server) searches the given path, then `path\symbols` and then `path\symbols\dll` (with *dll* being the files extensions). I didn't want to change your answer too much or add to much extraneous information.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [special `cache*path` token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx) in your WinDbg symbol path, WinDbg will cache symbols from sources following that token. It's also possible to write `srv*localpath*serverpath` to cache symbols from `serverpath` to `localpath`. If you don't want caching, make sure that your `.sympath` doesn't include it.

Also, it might be worth it to check if the symbols are effectively cached (fetched once, reused many times) or just stored there for this WinDbg run (fetched once per session).

Comment: It is essentially cached, are fetched only once and it stays there for ever. Subsequent `.reloads` are fast. If I delete this folder contents than again the `.reload` is slower when it actually fetches the symbols.