# Sqlserver.exe has stopped working

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, updates

Since installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 I have been getting the below error. It happens only when Visual Studio 2015 is open and happens whether I am running as a local admin or not. It is frequent and is irritating, but does not seem to affect any work that I am doing. Code, Server Explorer, VS all work fine bat the error messages popping up and Microsoft Error Reporting taking up long periods of 50% usage of my CPU in the process.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't want to spend hours trying to resolve it.

**Error Message:**

[image]

**In my Application event log I see the following:**

> Fault bucket 126419871336, type 5 Event Name: SQLException64 Response:
>   Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: sqlservr.exe P2: 0.0.0.0 P3: 0000000000000000
>   P4: sqlmin.dll P5: 2015.130.1601.5 P6: 000000005724AE98 P7:
>   -1073741819 P8: 0000000000064BB2 P9: 00000001D8D946AB P10:
>
> Attached files: \?\C:\Users\m_f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server Local DB\Instances\ProjectsV13\SQLDump0100.mdmp
>   \?\C:\Users\m_f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\ProjectsV13\SQLDump0100.txt
>   \?\C:\Users\m_f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\ProjectsV13\SQLDump0100.log
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERE021.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_sqlservr.exe_7113a987f49ac660cb71f97cb4183ea19827ef0_00000000_0bd7e949
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report ID:
>   3e38065a-5d62-11e6-89a7-97ade4354400 Report Status: 1 Hashed bucket:
>   ff995718a61d049a3664662b84518798

**And in the SQL log:**

> Process 49 generated fatal exception c0000005
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.

Is also seems to have been a known issue - see [this Microsoft KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/972936) that says it has been patched.

My system is as up to date as possible in terms of OS, patches, security updates, Visual Studio updates etc but I still see the issue. Hopefully someone has solved this before and can save me some frustration trying to get it sorted!

Thanks

Comment: create a full crash dump (**procdump -ma -i C:\localdumps**), open the dmp in Windbg, fix the symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run **!analyze -v** and look what you can see

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an ongoing thread about this crash on Microsoft's MSDN forum:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c486ed7-9fdb-45f0-9fcd-342eadbb0476/sqlserverexe-crashing

Apparently, this crash occurs after upgrading to the most recent version of SSDT (14.0.60525.0).

A Microsoft employee suggested this as a fix:

> We've investigated and believe that this happens when the query store feature is enabled in any database in the localdb server.  You can work around this problem by disabling the query store feature in all localdb database instances.
>   To find the names of databases that have query store enabled, run this query:
>
> `select [name] from sys.databases where is_query_store_on=1`
>
> Then for each database, disable query store by executing a query like so:
>
> `alter database DBNAME set query_store=off`

Some reported this did not fix the issue for them, others that it did, so your success may vary.

See Microsoft employee Kevin Cunnane's comment below:

> The fixed LocalDB.msi is included in the August release - available from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx with update via the Visual Studio Extensions and Updates channel due in the next few weeks.

Comment: The fixed LocalDB.msi is included in the August release - available from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx with update via the Visual Studio Extensions and Updates channel due in the next few weeks.

Comment: @KevinCunnane As of 3/27/2017 this issue is not fixed.  I'm running VS2017 and SSMS 13.0.16106.4

Answer (score 5):

On your localDb run following script

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(max)   


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM  sys.databases 
WHERE is_query_store_on=1 and name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

set @query = 'alter database  ['+ @name+']    set query_store=off'
      EXECUTE(  @query)

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

this will fix problem for all databases

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old'ish post, but the issue is rearing up again since VS 2017 it seems... at least with my (SSDT) SQL database project... so in the hopes that this might help someone else...

The accepted answer works perfectly but is quite manual. The script provided by Mahdi makes it a little bit more automated. In both cases, however, you might (depending on your build/deploy setup) need to run the script on both of the `master` databases on `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` and `(localdb)\projectsv1`, respectively.

In addition, the problem is that the property keeps getting restored every time you build and run with `F5`. As it turns out, though, there is a setting on the **Debug** tab of the project properties page, called **Deploy database properties**... clear (uncheck) this setting to ensure that the issue doesn't come back.

Note that: a) this is only for **Debug** mode; and b) it is only applicable to databases under (localdb).

[image: project properties page - debug tab]