# "sqlservr.exe has stopped working" error keep showing up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

It keeps showing that error msg 1 per 30 mins. It still works after I close the error prompts. It's just super annoying to have that unmeaningful error msg.

Comment: I wonder if the sql server instance is still working in the background?

Comment: How many instances have you installed?

Comment: please check: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c486ed7-9fdb-45f0-9fcd-342eadbb0476/sqlserverexe-crashing?forum=ssdt

Comment: what do you see in the SQL Server error log and windows event log (app)? Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829659/sqlserver-exe-has-stopped-working

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I noticed that it only happens when I AzureStorageEmulator.exe running.

Comment: The error may be from other service depends on sql service.Review log events of windows system/application for that error.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829659/sqlserver-exe-has-stopped-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlserver.exe has stopped working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829659/sqlserver-exe-has-stopped-working)

Comment: @DavidL definitely a duplicate.  I had the same problem and the other post fixed my problem.  This question should be closed - flagged it.