# VS 2017 sqlservr.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So I've read some other messages about this and deleted everything in:
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\ProjectsV13

then it all gets re-created.  I don't want a local database, but what do I have to do to get rid of this error.  This only happens when I open 2017 Visual Studio.
Anything I can do.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041038)... Mine was crashing not only on opening VS but also periodically after that. This fixed the issue.

Essentially, MS discovered that this happens only with databases on the localdb server that has the query store feature enabled, and the workaround for now is to disable that particular feature on all of those databases.

**Edit:** Based on the feedback in the comments below, I'll mention here that I've expanded a bit on the answer in [this subsequent response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727455/6641764) - it helps to prevent the issue from returning when you rebuild your solution.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I have no localdb server.  I even tried to install one and that didn't do anything

Comment: LocalDb is installed as part of Visual Studio 2017... you can access your instances through the "SQL Server Object Explorer" window...

`View -> SQL Server Object Explorer` ... then, under the "SQL Server" node, you'll see `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and `(localdb)\ProjectsV13`

Comment: Oh, also, I've expanded a bit on the previous answer in [this subsequent response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43727455/6641764) - it helps to prevent the issue from returning when you rebuild your solution.

Comment: The comment post just above seems to be the answer.  I had to close and re-open and it seems better now.  really strange.  thank you

Comment: Thanks @dan-parker I've updated the answer to reflect this feedback. If your issue was resolved, please consider marking the answer.