# Frequently getting SQL server stopped working error window

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm frequently getting the below error window, how can this be avoided or what need to be done for this?

[image]

System specifications:

```
SQL server 2008 R2
Windows server 2008 standard
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the event viewer for details. Its hard to tell.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829659/sqlserver-exe-has-stopped-working and this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c486ed7-9fdb-45f0-9fcd-342eadbb0476/sqlserverexe-crashing?forum=ssdt

Comment: @ttwis, I have checked with above link but no luck, not working.

Comment: @plaidDK, Which category need to checked in event viewer for details? System/Application etc..

Comment: @MagendranV Im not sure, im not that much into event viewer besides i know you can get details about your error. Maybe look under application. Check the timestamp where it failed and look for it in the event viewer