# Visual Studio community install crash

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the following error whenever I try to install Visual Studio Community from the [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs/?sku=community&clcid=0x409&downloadrename=true) site. It occurs immediately upon running the `exe`.

[image]

I have downloaded many versions, run as admin, restarted my pc etc etc, and every time I am hit with this error. I have had visual studio installed on this PC previously.

Selecting "Close program" ironically opens this [site](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-install-vs/?lang=ct!!B57121FA9E9049F19A21F91AC45F5D42). Which is evidently no help.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this before I attempt to contact Microsoft Support?

Event Viewer is displaying the following information;

```
Windows Error Reporting >>

Fault bucket 126880939415, type 5
Event Name: VSSetup
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: vs_community
P2: 14.0.25420.01.00
P3: 14.0.25420
P4: Modify
P5: unknown
P6: Crash: Exception
P7: 573d30d8
P8: 2d00
P9: 87
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Users\Zze\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20161013195641.log
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER20D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_vs_community_75ac19b40c3da27636257b32fb6b4ecbe966b21_00000000_113e12a7

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: f78c6647-9122-11e6-b683-408d5c133079
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 71915888af88bf9f710ea44204d852b2
```

Comment: Is there error in event viewer?

Comment: update the GPU drivers, I saw some crashes because of old GPU drivers

Comment: configure WER (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) to generate a crash dump, open the dmp in windbg, setup the symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run **!analyze -v** and look if you can see anything useful

Comment: have you seen anything useful in the dmp?

Comment: @magicandre1981 honestly I haven't been back to this yet - I have been away. As soon as I try again I will update.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Still yet to do this - will do this weekend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the some problem. I resolved launched the vs_communnity.exe with the parameter /log

vscommunity..exe /log log.txt

Then I opened the log and I discovered that was a font problem. I found this support on microsoft website https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2978135 and finally I resolved the issue.

I hope this can help you

Comment: I have so many fonts installed, for me I couldn't figure out which ones were causing the issue so I just backed up all my fonts, deleted them, installed VS, then put the fonts back

Comment: You are correct, there was a font error exception being thrown! @NicoWesterdale Your suggestion is 10/10! All fixed now - thanks!!!