# Unable to Install Visual Studio 2019 -- Bootstrap Installer Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I recently had a bug with Windows Visual Studio 2017 that caused me to decide to uninstall it and do a reinstall.  At the time I decided to also upgrade to VS2019. During the uninstall I was unable to run the VS Uninstaller, and had to do a manual uninstall as per the instructions found in the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

After this small, private odyssey I download the latest [bootstrap installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16) from Microsoft, and get an .exe file named vs_community__827122640.1559901191 .  Anytime I try to run this installer it will download the necessary files, and then install them, afterword a small blue circle will show up and the installer will say ["Almost done ... Getting everything ready."](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmGyMX6WzP4cinqZ4oqu2ZMZvAiX?e=67diAf) and after about 45 seconds will crash.  I have checked the task manager and it does not appear to still be running as a background task or process after the crash.  I have tried a variety of things to remedy this issue, including:

- Rebooting the computer
- Re-downloading the installer
- Manually removing registry entries related to the Visual Studio
- Deleting items in %temp%
- Deleting items in %programdata% and similar as referenced in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb90b356-5444-4f22-bad6-642a3abd3882/installation-error-on-vs-enterprise-2017?forum=vssetup).
- Removing items in the folders suggested by this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d14916e8-8a2f-4a22-9f4c-0d96e02d79dc/cant-set-up-vs-2019?forum=vssetup).
- Running a Microsoft Executable that would [identify and fix problems related to blocking installations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed), also suggested by this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d14916e8-8a2f-4a22-9f4c-0d96e02d79dc/cant-set-up-vs-2019?forum=vssetup), but was unable to identify any issues.
- Running the Microsoft Visual Studio Uninstaller available from the Microsoft [Github Repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller).
- Running from command line and with admin privileges the [Microsoft InstallCleanup.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).
- Running the installer with admin privileges.
- Running Windows Update, downloading relevant updates and rebooting.

Honestly, I'm kind of at wits end here, and the only thing I have seen in the Microsoft visual studio developer forums that states the problem was solved after [user reinstalled Windows](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/591518/visual-studio-installer-stuck-on-getting-things-re.html), which I want to avoid at all costs, though I also did follow the other suggestions on that forum.  Similar forums have requested that users upload their Visual Studio log files, which I have done [according to these instructions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/can-get-visual-studio-installation-logs/) and uploaded to OneDrive [at this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmGyMX6WzP4cinsU4vj_TX8LKLbR?e=itPf3u).  Any help that anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.  My system information is that I am using an Intel based computer running Windows 10 Home (64-bit). Windows Update says I am on Windows 10, version 1909.  Like I said, any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Most time Microsoft installer may be depending on some libraries most the windows .net framework. so if is VisualStudio 2019, it will depend on the latest dotnet versions. So I guess you see if you can make sure at least the dotnet versions are updated, starting from 2.5 to the highest. Also, C++ redistributable can also be the cause of the crash, since the installer or the application may be depending on the existing old versions. so i suggest you check your system to be sure the version you're using is current.

Comment: Note: Check the Microsoft website to see what the installer is depending on, either all the prerequisite that you are to do or suppose to do before the installer. I can't really say is the operating system, sometimes uninstalling your operating system may not necessarily fix the problem, when the OS still is missing those required files.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997089/visual-studio-community-install-crash

Comment: Thanks @Dexter's the font issue you shared was indeed interesting, but does not appear to be the problem. As for the .net framework I checked the prerequisites, re-downloaded and updated them, so it is the most up-to-date version.

Comment: okay. i will check for other possible solutions. I wish you luck