# Visual Studio C++ 2015 community edition opencv 3.1.0 cannot find or open the pdb file

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I have tried to setup VS 15 with opencv 3.1.0 but when I start debugging encountered following stacktrace.

I've selected checkbox in Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols still no change. Even I have reinstalled visual studio, but got the same error.

Also changed Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working Directory to use the value from Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Output Directory. Even running visual studio with administrative privilege not working.

```
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\FYP Workspace\VS 15\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv3\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world310.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\concrt140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_34ae2abd958aedeb\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
 The program '[6156] Project2.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: have you added the MS symbol server to the debugging/symbol server option in VS?

Comment: yes, I already did. :/

Comment: add the MS symbol server on your own, not the predefined entry: srv*C:\Symbols *https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;

Comment: sorry, did you meant specifying new cache symbol directory?

Comment: add https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols as a new entry and also try a different symbol cache folder

Comment: still getting the error..

Comment: run the app without debugging and use ProcessExplorer to generate a full dump. Open the dmp in Windbg , setup the symbols in windbg (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run **.reload /f** to download all PDBs. Now use the folder where you downloaded the PDBs in VS and look if you can debug the app now

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it so far according to your information. All other symbols loading except still getting the error of "couldn't load pdb for opencv"

Comment: build opencv on your own: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.1.0 and add the generated PDBs to the symbol cache

Comment: then i got "LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27_d.lib' " while building the opencv source using visual studio.

Comment: this is the debug version of python 2.7. compile as release and not debug