# How to debug / analyze BSOD dump in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, crash-dumps, bsod

I had BSOD and it created DMP file in C:\Windows\Minidump. Then I opened this file with Visual Studion with File -> Open -> Crash Dump. It opens something, but nothing reasonable can be seen.

Is this correct way to start analyzing crash dumps?

What should I see in VS for it?

Can I see call stack for example?

The following appears in `Debugger Immediate Window`:

[image]

The similar appears with WinDbg:

[image]

No any keys or commands can be entered anywhere.

Comment: It looks like the symbols are still being loaded from the Microsoft symbol server. Is there any network traffic in this situation? How long have you been waiting? (Sometimes it takes a couple of minutes until the load of the symbols is completed.) Also check in WinDbg if the `File --> Symbol File Path` is set to `SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`. If you want to speed up the symbol load time for the next debugging session, you could configure a local symbol cache.

Comment: The output of `!analyze -v` is too short. That command has not finished yet. Your symbol path is is empty, so [fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyze the dmps in Windbg. Get WinDbg via the [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk). During Setup select the `Debugging Tools for Windows`.

Now run `Windbg.exe`, load the dmp, [fix your debug symbol path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run `!analyze -v` to [start the automatic debugging](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks). Look in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433.aspx) what the STOP code means and the other commands that you can use to debug the issue deeper.

Comment: It seems that the OP has already installed/started WinDbg and loaded the dmp.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "Requirements and limitations" in this document here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx, when a kernel-mode error occurs, the default behavior of Microsoft Windows is to display the blue screen with bug check data, to debug kernel-mode dump files in Visual Studio 2013, you need to download the Windows 8.1 Version of Debugging Tools for Windows.

About how to perform kernel-mode debugging in Microsoft Visual Studio:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451163(v=vs.85).aspx

About how to debug the windows dump file using the Windbg tool, you could get detailed steps here:

http://timtrott.co.uk/debug-windows-crash-dumps-minidump/

Like haindl's suggestion, you have to download the symbols from the Microsoft Server.