# How do I analyse C# prodump crash dump file, an exception came from the CLR?

Tags: c#, clr, windbg, dump, procdump

hi i am new in inspecting crash dump file and i need help or method how to.
 I can see that exception came from CLR and `"clr exception - code e0434352(first chance)"`
I have attached the dump file drive can be downloaded here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWisplLq-PqLXppb1IzMV9VVGs

any helps appreciated.

Comment: use DebugDiag2 analyzer it gives you a HTML overview of everything it detects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic analysis is `!analyze -v`, which already helps in your case. Make sure your [symbols are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg) first. So the following 3 commands are enough to find out the exception:

```
0:000> .symfix
0:000> .reload
0:000> !analyze -v
[...]
CLR_EXCEPTION
    Tid    [0x0]
    Frame  [0x00]

    String [System.ArgumentNullException]
    Failure Bucketing
    Data Bucketing

BUGCHECK_STR:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.ArgumentNullException    
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_System.ArgumentNullException
[...]
```

For .NET, there's also an extension called [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) which can help:

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
0:000> !pe
Exception object: 00000000045ff3b8
Exception type:   System.ArgumentNullException
Message:          Value cannot be null.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    00000000003EDC20 000007FEDB83F49D System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[[System.Byte, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Byte>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Byte>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<Byte>)+0x22d

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004003
```

You probably also need the call stack:

```
0:000> !clrstack
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17929
SOS Version: 4.6.1590.0
OS Thread Id: 0x1b50 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
00000000003edb38 0000000077c7bd7a [HelperMethodFrame: 00000000003edb38] 
00000000003edc20 000007fedb83f49c System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[[System.Byte, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1)
00000000003edc90 000007fe8d6be73f ILS.MasterController+c__DisplayClass4f.b__4d()
00000000003edd40 000007fedf9c971c System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
00000000003edda0 000007fedf9c9587 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
00000000003ede00 000007fedf9aa551 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
00000000003edec0 000007feeadaf8a5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
00000000003ee020 000007feeadaf609 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
00000000003ee050 000007feeadaf5c7 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
00000000003ee0a0 000007fedf9aa181 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
00000000003ee120 000007fedf9c74b1 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
00000000003ee1e0 000007fedf9c7813 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
00000000003ee2a0 000007fedf9c994a MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
00000000003ee350 000007fedf9c97d0 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
00000000003ee3a0 000007fedf9c95fe System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
00000000003ee400 000007fedf9c9587 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
00000000003ee460 000007fedf9c692c System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
00000000003ee500 000007fedf9c8e60 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
00000000003ee600 000007fedfb6e6e7 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
00000000003ee898 000007feec01482e [InlinedCallFrame: 00000000003ee898] MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
00000000003ee898 000007fedf9d39e0 [InlinedCallFrame: 00000000003ee898] MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
00000000003ee870 000007fedf9d39e0 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
00000000003ee940 000007fedf9c5eb2 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
00000000003ee9e0 000007fedc3172da System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
00000000003eea80 000007fedc316bd7 System.Windows.Application.Run()
00000000003eeac0 000007fe8c8d0107 ILS.App.Main()
00000000003eedf0 000007feebf6f713 [GCFrame: 00000000003eedf0]
```

Comment: ILS.MasterController+c__DisplayClass4f.b__4d() here  the first part is my clas name what is the part after  "+c_" what is that ? cause i have no funtion name ?

Comment: @AnilGadiyar: probably some generated class/method from an anonymous function, lambda or some WPF stuff. I don't exactly tell.