# Visual Studio crashes when I associate my app with the store

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I tried to Associate my app with the Windows Store, Visual Studio 2015(Update 3) crashes.

[image: VS2015 crash]

Solution tried,

1. Run as Administrator - No use.
2. Repair in Program and Features - No use.
3. .NET Framework Repair Tool - No use.
4. Running devenv /Resetsettings in CMD - No use.
5. Running devenv /Safemode in CMD - If is open in safe mode I can't use associate my app with the store feature, so No use.
6. Tried to use "Create App Packages" instead of "Associate App with the store" - Still Crashes.

Please help.

Comment: try to update to update 3?

Comment: @DaveSmits I am Sorry, VS automatically updated to Update 3. So I have the latest version

Comment: Configure WER (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) to generate a full crash dump (DumpType must be set to 2), open the dmp in windbg, setup the symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run **!analyze -v** and look if you can see anything useful

Comment: have you seen anything useful in the dump?

Comment: @Vijay, I have reported this issue to related team, so I will update here if I get any information. You can also contact [dev center support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) through your developer account so that you will be assisted better. Please click "Submit an incident".

Comment: @magicandre1981 I found out some Extension like this -> Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\WINDOWS STORE SDK\...  I have give a link to my file https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhsM8UnfYgSDhf57pLkTIygUonrNPg

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Good to know. I don't have developer account because I have a problem with paying. Error: We can't authorize the payment method. Please make sure the information is correct, or use another payment method. If you continue to get this message, please contact your financial institution

Comment: we need a crash dump, this XML doesn't help

Comment: I had similar issue about a month back, unfortunately I had to uninstall VS and its components and then reinstall it back.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is my dump file. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhsM8UnfYgSDhqkeIl9qnSOA8LBZ5Q

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is the result of !analyze -v https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhsM8UnfYgSDhqkfNBnnzMhP9XqXuA

Comment: I posted what I saw from the dump

Comment: have you checked that your account is a registered dev account that can submit apps?

Comment: @magicandre1981, thanks for analyzing the issue. We have been able to reproduce the problem and are investigating the bug - from a fix perspective.

Comment: @PrashantHPhadke-MSFT ok, thanks for looking at the issue. Hopefully you can improve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a [System.ArgumentNullException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx):

```
0:000>  !sos.pe 0x27bc6888 
Exception object: 27bc6888
Exception type:   System.ArgumentNullException
Message:          Value cannot be null.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    00B3D220 061D9606 UNKNOWN!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowArgumentNull(System.String)+0x3e
    00B3D22C 061D9137 UNKNOWN!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductViewModel+<ReserveProductNameAsync>d__103.MoveNext()+0x77
    00B3D318 712CFFB1 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x5d
    00B3D328 712CCA43 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x3b
    00B3D334 061D8F00 UNKNOWN!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductViewModel+<ReserveProductNameAsync>d__93.MoveNext()+0x1c8
    00B3D3E0 712CFFB1 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x5d
    00B3D3F0 712CCA43 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x3b
    00B3D3FC 061D87C7 UNKNOWN!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductViewModel+<<InitializeCommands>b__97_2>d.MoveNext()+0x8f
    00B3D6EC 71B823ED mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(System.Object)+0x35
    00B3D6F4 649319C0 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+0xd0
    00B3D714 64931884 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)+0x34
    00B3D758 64933FFB WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()+0xab
    00B3D790 64933F4C WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)+0x3c
    00B3D798 71321512 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0xc2
    00B3D804 71321446 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0x16
    00B3D818 71321401 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x41
    00B3D830 64933D63 WindowsBase_ni!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x63
    00B3D860 64933C0E WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()+0x4e
    00B3D894 64930365 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()+0x165
    00B3D8D4 6493055A WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)+0x5a
    00B3D920 64931B2B WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)+0x9b
    00B3D95C 64931A7B WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)+0x6b
    00B3D96C 6493193E WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+0x4e
    00B3D98C 64931884 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)+0x34
    00B3D9D0 6492FEDB WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+0x10b
    00B3DA2C 6493140E WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)+0xee
    00000000 00000001 WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)+0x2
    00B3DC64 6492F551 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)+0xb1
    00B3DCB0 6492F24A WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)+0x4a
    00B3DCBC 61F7F1DE PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object)+0xcdaad2
    00B3DCE4 612A02BE PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.Show()+0x62
    00B3DCF0 61A48EE9 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()+0x305
    00B3DD3C 1B914795 Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_14_0_ni!Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.WindowHelper.ShowModal(System.Windows.Window, IntPtr)+0x175
    00B3DD70 1B91451C Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_14_0_ni!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DialogWindow.ShowModal()+0x1c
    00B3DD84 1B914375 UNKNOWN!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WizardFrameworkWpf.WizardBase.ShowModal()+0x35
    00B3DD94 01940BDF UNKNOWN!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.Commands.CommandsPackage+<AssociateAppWithStoreExec>d__56.MoveNext()+0x97
    00B3F47C 71B823ED mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(System.Object)+0x35
    00B3F484 649319C0 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+0xd0
    00B3F4A4 64931884 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)+0x34
    00B3F4E8 64933FFB WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()+0xab
    00B3F520 64933F4C WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)+0x3c
    00B3F528 71321512 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0xc2
    00B3F594 71321446 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0x16
    00B3F5A8 71321401 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x41
    00B3F5C0 64933D63 WindowsBase_ni!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x63
    00B3F5F0 64933C0E WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()+0x4e
    00B3F624 64930365 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()+0x165
    00B3F664 6493055A WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)+0x5a
    00B3F6B0 64931B2B WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)+0x9b
    00B3F6EC 64931A7B WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)+0x6b
    00B3F6FC 6493193E WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+0x4e
    00B3F71C 64931884 WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)+0x34
    00B3F760 6492FEDB WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+0x10b
    00B3F7BC 6493140E WindowsBase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)+0xee
```

In the enumerator `Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductViewModel+<ReserveProductNameAsync>d__103.MoveNext()+0x77`.

I also see that you get `Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductException` with this message:

> Your Microsoft account is not registered to submit apps to the Store.
>   To register or check your registration, go to the Windows Store web
>   site.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductViewModel+<SignIntoStoreAsync>d__80.MoveNext() 
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppxPackage.PickProductViewModel+<SetSelectedAccount>d__88.MoveNext()
```

So, make sure your [Microsoft Account is registered to submit apps to the store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account).

Comment: My bank account doesn't support international transactions. The problem wouldn't be resolved unless I create a new bank account. It would take me some time to create one, so until then I can't verify if the solution works or not. If it works I would be sure to mark the solution as the answer. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble to open support ticket due to payment issue, I'd recommend you to send feedback from Visual Studio.

To send feedback click the button as per first screenshot below

[image]

**Report a Problem**->**Create a New issue**->Provide details in the next screen and make sure that you expands the "**Record your actions**" and "**Start Recording**" – second screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I sent Feedback without Recording because after completing recording it open a dialog box says "we were trying to display the visual studio feedback dialog but a modal dialog is blocking us. Dismiss any modal dialogs in visual Studio before retrying."

Comment: @Vijay Nirmal, no worries, the Feedback is not necessary at this point. We have been able to reproduce the problem/ bug and are investigating the Visual Studio crash. However, please make sure that you associate your Microsoft account with the Store after which you should be able to Reserve an app name. Sorry about the experience.

Comment: @PrashantHPhadke-MSFT I hope they will display an error message instead of crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 (VS crash after trying to reserve the app name).

So I opened my project in Visual Studio 2017 I would get the proper error message:

> The store blocked this account. Ensure the account has permission to read reserved app names and that it is linked to a valid Developer subscription.

[image]

Comment: Only above Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.14)