# Visual Studio 2015 update 3 has stopped working on startup?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed some components additionally.

Xamarin, Telerik UI, Android SDK.

So I have been working for weeks ago but VS2015 has stopped work on startup.

My VS2015 is a trial version.

[image]

Please help me!!!

Comment: Configure WER (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) to generate a full crash dump (DumpType must be set to 2), open the dmp in windbg, setup the symbols (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046) and run **!analyze -v** and look if you can see anything useful

Comment: were you able to create dumps and analyze them?