# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when starting debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, crash

When compiling my C++ project or running it, everything is fine.
But when starting my project with the debugger, Visual Studio 2015 crashes.
I tried [this](http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/), I have found two errors:

```
<entry>
  <record>484</record>
  <time>2017/02/14 14:09:32.187</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>Color Theme Service</source>
  <description>The color &apos;Popup&apos; in category &apos;de7b1121-99a4-4708-aedf-15f40c9b332f&apos; does not exist.</description>
</entry>
```

and

```
<entry>
<record>558</record>
  <time>2017/02/14 14:10:08.617</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Loading UI library</description>
  <guid>{8C0C630B-37F1-11E3-8259-6C3BE516EAD0}</guid>
  <hr>800a006f</hr>
</entry>
```

I don't know what to do to make VS's debugger work.

Edit: I use the dark theme if this can help...

Comment: Define "it crashes".

Comment: I see the "Microsoft Windows Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working" and a few seconds after that, VS closes itself.

Comment: Does the system's Event Log not contain a code you can use to contact Microsoft for help?

Comment: I don't know if it's useful or not but in the Administrative events, I have three events related to my problem, two are named "Application Error" and the third one is named ".NET runtime", they all says "Name of failing application: devenv.exe", the code for the two first one is 1000 and the code for the .NET runtime is 1026

Comment: I assume you have already tried reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: Nope, I didn't and tbh I want to avoid this

Comment: generate a crash dump and analyze it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971066/visual-studio-2015-update-3-has-stopped-working-on-startup#comment71147484_41971066

Comment: Okay, I got this in the command window: http://pastebin.com/07ZYUi9N do you need the call stack ?

Comment: this is NULL_POINTER_WRITE. we can't fix this. submit the issue via the IDE and submit the actual dmp file to Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that whether all projects have the same issue or just the specific one.

(1) Collect the crashed dump file and debugging it is also a good suggestion for the crashed issue.

(2) I also provide some suggestions which could narrow down this issue.

- Please uncheck symbols server under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols.
- Uncheck "Edit and continue", "Load dll exports (native only)" and "enable just my code(managed only)". Debug it again.
- Disable the IntelliTrace under TOOLS->Options->IntelliTrace, and "Use Native Compatibility Mode" under TOOLS->Option->Debugging->General or mix mode/native debugging project property(right click project->Debugging). Test it again.

I met the crashed issue before which was related to certain settings, so if possible, you could test it in your side.

But if all projects have the same issue, I suggest you repair your VS, or install the latest update package for your VS, and then debug it again.

If just one specific project has this issue, we would think about the project itself.

**Update:**

As our discussion, I found that you have reported this issue here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/3123487

I will help you vote it and add my comment there. If I get any latest information from the report team, I will update it here.

Comment: I already posted (1) http://pastebin.com/07ZYUi9N and for (2), I did everything but the last part (I don't know where to find these settings) and it still crashes, I tried with an empty console project.

Comment: @Random Coder 99, so an empty console app still has this issue, am I right? Could you close all third party processes/tools in your windows? Also run VS in safe mode(devenv.exe /safemode), how about the result? If possible, please also collect the setup log messages, we also need to make sure that it is not the setup issue. Please use http://aka.ms/vscollect  to gather the VS and .Net Frameowrk installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.cab from %temp% folder. Analyze the dump, you can report it here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx

Comment: Same with safe mode. I ran the collect.exe but there was no vslogs.cab, only vslogs.zip, and these was no .cab file in that zip as well.

Comment: @Random Coder 99, could you share us the zip log file? To analyze the dump file, you could report it to the connect site, I think you would get useful information there.

Comment: @Random Coder 99, no setup error in your log file, so it would be not the VS setup issue. Does it have this issue when you use the VS IDE for the first time? Did you install certain extension tools or add-ins? Could you collect the crashed dump file and report it to the connect report site?

Comment: It had this issue when I used VS on the first time on this computer. On another one, I had no issue. I installed some extensions, but VS crashed too in safe mode so I guess it's not that. By the crashed dump file, you mean the .dmp file ? If yes, it's too huge (80 MB) to upload it on microsoft connect, I'll try to upload it at another site

Comment: @Random Coder 99, yes, it is the .dmp file. I update my previous answer since you have reported this issue to the connect team, I also vote and add my comment there. In addition, if possible, you could mark the previous reply as the temporary answer, so other community members could find the same issue and the connect report easily, and then vote this report. Of course, I will follow up your connect report, if I get any latest information from the report team experts, I will update it here in time. Thanks for your support:)

Comment: Okay, the files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2CpMyD4TNmBZURUZTVhVk1yM2M?usp=sharing I'll put the link on connect too. There is only your answer, so I think other community members will see the link to connect topic quickly

Comment: @Random Coder 99,  the product team shared the latest information in that connect report "it has been fixed in VS2017", if possible, you could use the VS2017 RC and test it even if the RTM was not released now. Of course, I also help you add the comment, so we could get more detailed information from the product team experts:)

Comment: Installed VS 2017 RC, can't reproduce the bug

Comment: @RandomCoder99， if so, I suggest you use the VS2017 RC now, the RTM version will be released soon.

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't support the VS2017 RC? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WholeTomatoSoftware.VisualAssist, it seems that it has been updated.

Comment: @RandomCoder99, I down load it in my side(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WholeTomatoSoftware.VisualAssist), it really supports the VS2017 RC version. See: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auvjmr9ZOuhVhwf_hQz1mCw7Xobt, so please make sure that you use the latest RC version (RC4), or you could open the "Extensions and updates" windows, one possible reason is that it has been installed before.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know what I did but I have the VA extension set up correctly now. Others extensions as well. I'm using VS2017 now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue to this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visualstudio-crashes-while-debugging/915932.
The Windows event log indicates that **vsdebug.dll crashed**.

Crash Log:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 16.4.29806.167, time stamp: 0x5e3cf159
Faulting module name: vsdebug.dll, version: 16.0.29724.72, time stamp: 0x5e3129d2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0007cb70
Faulting process id: 0x522c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5e1b576573b00
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\vsdebug.dll
```

Solution:

1. Locate the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger".
2. Delete vsdebug.dll.
3. Copy vsdebug.dll from another PC to this one.
4. Enjoy it!