# Analyzing exception in crash dump

Tags: c#, windbg, crash-dumps

The client which uses my application gets crashes, so they sent me these two files `WER178D.tmp.hdmp` and `WER1868.tmp.mdmp`. I open first of it in WinDbg. Unfortunately I have no idea what to do here. I know this is way too broad of a question, but can I please get some initial guidance?

[image]

Comment: Try following this tutorial http://forums.majorgeeks.com/index.php?threads/how-to-debug-memory-dumps-figure-out-what-is-causing-a-bsod.35246/

Comment: Hope this blog is useful for you http://stevestechspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're using the right version of WinDbg. Use the 64 bit version of 64 bit crash dumps and the 32 bit version for 32 bit crash dumps. (I can see from the registers and the addresses, you seem to have done that right.)

Next, [fix your symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg). Without correct symbols, you might get wrong or misleading results.

If you have no clue, try `!analyze -v`; for exceptions continue as below.

If you know it's an exception, switch to the exception record with `.ecxr` (you have done that).

Print the native exception details with `.exr -1`. If the exception code is `0xE0434F4D`, then it's a .NET exception. Be aware that there are some exceptions which do not have that code but still are .NET exceptions (e.g. `Access violation` which could be a `NullReferenceException`).

If it's a .NET application, load the .NET extension [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) with

```
.loadby sos clr
.loadby sos mscorwks
.loadby sos coreclr
```

for .NET 4, .NET 2 and Silverlight/.NET Core respectively. It succeeded if you don't get an error message.

Use `!pe` to print the details of the managed exception.