# Why i got wrong debug symbols?

Tags: dll, windbg, pdb-files, memory-dump

I have next workflow:

1) Build dll and pdb files.

2) Share dll to cutomer

3) Analize memory dump from customer.

When I run `!analyze -v` in `WinDbg` I got (below part of output)

```
....
MANAGED_STACK_COMMAND:  _EFN_StackTrace
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS
// some callstack here
MODULE_NAME: RTPLogic
IMAGE_NAME:  RTPLogic.dll
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  58a43706
STACK_COMMAND:  ~541s; .ecxr ; kb
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_c0000374_RTPLogic.dll!CSRTPStack::Finalize
BUCKET_ID:     X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_rtplogic!CSRTPStack::Finalize+1da
```

Looks like we have wrong debug symbol for `RTPLogic.dll`.
I download `ChkMatch` tool.
I get pdb path from `windbg`

```
0:541> !lmi RTPlogic.dll
Loaded Module Info: [rtplogic.dll] 
         Module: RTPLogic
.....
            Age: 1, Pdb: D:\Work\path_to_original_pdb\RTPLogic.pdb
     Image Type: MEMORY   - Image read successfully from loaded memory.
    Symbol Type: PDB      - Symbols loaded successfully from image header.
                 C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\RTPLogic.pdb\9F82CDF359044635ADEBA578CA1D1D031\RTPLogic.pdb
       Compiler: Resource - front end [0.0 bld 0] - back end [9.0 bld 21022]
    Load Report: private symbols & lines, not source indexed 
                 C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\RTPLogic.pdb\9F82CDF359044635ADEBA578CA1D1D031\RTPLogic.pdb
```

I have logs related to this dump and I see that my changes appears in logs. So customer not forgotten to install my DLL before get the memdump.
I run `ChkMatch`

```
PS D:\tools> .\ChkMatch.exe -c "D:\Work\path_to_dll\RTPLogic.dll" "C:\Progra
mData\dbg\sym\RTPLogic.pdb\9F82CDF359044635ADEBA578CA1D1D031\RTPLogic.pdb"
.....
Result: Matched
```

How it possible that I got wrong debug symbols in such situation?

Comment: That's too little information, too vague. Could you post some concrete output, please? What's the exact output of ChkMatch, what's the exact warning text in WinDbg. What's the symbol path? Do both tools really use the same files? Post the output of `lm`, `.symopt` and `.sympath` in WinDbg. Normally WinDbg does not load non-matching symbols at all. If it does, you have already "tweaked" something

Comment: Ok, but now it looks like different question

Comment: What you added to the question confirms what I had in mind. I can now answer your question with more confidence. +1 for following up and providing the necessary information

Comment: c0000374 = heap corruption, activate appverifier/pageheap to detect the real cause, the corruption happend way before your finalizer tries to free the memory.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just want to understand do I have all debug symbols to continue investigation with those flag. I afraid that memory corruption is the reason why I see "wrong debug symbols".

Answer (score 1):

The symbols for `RTPLogic.dll!CSRTPStack::Finalize` are correct, but other symbols that are required to reconstruct the call stack are incorrect. It's likely that you have some operating system methods on the call stack and the symbols for `ntdll` or similar are missing.

Since with ChkMatch, you're only checking one single PDB file, the result of ChkMatch is as reliable and correct (for one PDB) as that of WinDbg (for many PDBs) and they do not contradict each other.

Your sympath probably contains only a local path to your own DLLs and does not contain any information about Microsoft's symbol server. In the output of `.sympath` (which you did not post), I expect to see something like

```
0:000> .sympath
D:\Work\path_to_dll
```

You should include Microsoft symbols as well, as described in [How to set up symbols in WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg). To fix the problem, use the following commands:

```
.symfix+ c:\symbols
.reload /f
```

The output of `.sympath` should now look like

```
0:000> .sympath
D:\Work\path_to_dll;SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

This should help WinDbg in reconstructing the complete call stack, resolve OS methods of `ntdll` and others and thus get rid of the "wrong symbols" message.