# How to see friendly .NET call stacks?

Tags: c#, windbg, pdb-files, memory-dump

I got a memory dump. I can get the normal callstack (with line number)
When I use Debug Diag to analyze the dump I got this callstack on thread 62.

```
.NET Call Stack

[[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ] (System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative)] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)+21 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean)+31 
CaptureServices.GenericInfrastructure.ExportLogic.ChannelsThread.ChannelsStateThread()+bb 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+15e 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+17 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+52 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()+52 
[[GCFrame]] 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
```

As I understand .NET has some mechanism to shows human readable names instead of adresses. Now I want this line in WinDbg:

```
CaptureUtilities.AudioProcessing.APProcessorThread.IterateAPStreamProcessorQueue()+49
```

I open WinDbg and load the dump. I execute `~62 k` and get

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000016`4965e0c8 00007ffc`b59113ed ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
00000016`4965e0d0 00007ffc`abde77be KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe1
00000016`4965e3b0 00007ffc`abde7658 clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x62
00000016`4965e410 00007ffc`abde7451 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x1e4
00000016`4965e510 00007ffc`abdebd15 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
00000016`4965e590 00007ffc`a94ecdf1 clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x165
00000016`4965e7c0 00007ffc`a94ecdc1 mscorlib_ni+0x48cdf1
00000016`4965e7f0 00007ffc`4cf2e97b mscorlib_ni+0x48cdc1
00000016`4965e830 00007ffc`a94e674e 0x00007ffc`4cf2e97b
00000016`4965e890 00007ffc`a94e65e7 mscorlib_ni+0x48674e
00000016`4965e960 00007ffc`a94e65a2 mscorlib_ni+0x4865e7
00000016`4965e990 00007ffc`a94ed1f2 mscorlib_ni+0x4865a2
00000016`4965e9e0 00007ffc`abc36a53 mscorlib_ni+0x48d1f2
00000016`4965ea20 00007ffc`abc36913 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
```

Ok, as I understand it is the same. Now we have

```
0x00007ffc`4cf2e97b
```

instead of

```
CaptureServices.GenericInfrastructure.ExportLogic.ChannelsThread.ChannelsStateThread()+bb
```

So I have Microsoft debug symbols, now I need to load my own symbols to see the callstack.
The question is - do I need to load all debug symbols for my projects or I need only debug symbols for dll which contains `CaptureServices.GenericInfrastructure.ExportLogic`?
Or maybe I need to load only part of my debug symbols to handle this thread?

Comment: Where did you get `IterateAPStreamProcessorQueue` from? It's not in the call stack

Answer (score 1):

Try `!sosex.mk`. It gives a user-friendly stack trace with interleaved managed and native frames. I do not believe that this is a symbol issue. Also, when you have a managed address, you can pass it to `!sosex.mln` to see what's located there, but I think you're already aware of this command.

Answer (score 0):

The `k` command as in `~62k` is a command for the native call stack. It does dot show any .NET stuff (except the native methods in `clr.dll`).

To see the .NET stack, you need to load the .NET extension for WinDbg:

```
.loadby sos clr
```

And then use a command of that extension to see the .NET call stack. Switch to thread 62 first

```
~62s
!clrstack
!dumpstack
```

IMHO those commands will load symbols from PDBs when needed. If you get symbol warnings, see [How to fix symbols in WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Answer (score -1):

You need the debug symbols of whatever library that function belongs to.

Comment: Like, I don't even see the confusion, if you want symbolic data for an executable you need its symbol database (usually .pdb in Windows). What is throwing you for a loop here?

Comment: Maybe simple example will show my confusion.
Lets my project have 3 DLLs (A, D, C)
I know that on this thread I stuck in code of A. This code in A called from code of B and C is stand alone (not part of this call stack but part of other call stacks)
Which DLLs I need to see the callstack A, A+B, A+B+C?

Comment: Did you realize that this is for .NET and not for native code? It's not as simple as loading PDB files. WinDbg cannot debug .NET on its own.

Comment: @Thomas, what WinDbg can or cannot do is irrelevant, debug symbols are universal in Windows. If WinDbg can't handle JIT'd code, simply use a better debugger. But by all means, downvote a correct answer. Edit: You're also dead wrong, WinDbg can most certainly handle managed call stacks.

Comment: @StepanLoginov, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to see the call stack in A.dll? Then you need the debug symbols for A.dll (A.pdb, you'll find them in your Debug/Release folders).

Comment: As the top #1 Windbg answerer on SO, I doubt I'm wrong, but I'm glad I could learn something new, so if you find out how to show the .NET call stack without an extra extension, I'm willing to spend a +300 bounty.

Comment: A quick Google search shows this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/07/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-call-stacks-part-1/ -- you can see it's Microsoft's own link from MSDN, from 6 years ago. I don't know about extensions or not, but I don't see an issue with using them if required.