# Extract PDB and executable files from a symbol server using a crash dump

Tags: visual-studio-2015, symbols, crash-dumps

I'm able to debug almost any crash dump that my large organization generates because all symbols and relevant executables are stored compressed in a central symbol store location. There's never a problem until I need to send the crash dump along with all its relevant pdb's and executable files outside the company to debug a third party library.

The last time I did this, I had to perform a lot of trial and error to collect the files I needed from the symbol store, which is mostly machine organized and not very human readable. It would be great if I could open the crash dump and have Visual Studio extract and save out all the files I need from the symbol store to another folder so I can send it off for analysis.

Know of any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution for Visual Studio. However, this problem can be solved with WinDbg or SymChk from the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/index) which are provided by Microsoft for free.

According to my knowledge, a symbol server does only store PDBs and not executables, so the following instructions are for PDBs only.

There is a command for WinDbg, `!SaveAllModules`, which might work for saving all DLLs and executables which are present in the dump file. I don't have a lot experience with it.

## Steps in WinDbg

On a machine with Internet connection and connection to your company's symbol server

1. Open the crash dump in WinDbg
2. [Set up the symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg), e.g. add your company symbol server and the Microsoft symbol server. For the cache location, choose an empty directory.
3. run the commands `.reload /f` and `ld*`

This will download all available symbols into the defined directory.

## Steps for SymChk

On a machine with Internet connection and connection to your company's symbol server

1. From a command line prompt, run

   ```
   symchk /id <dumpfile>.dmp /s srv*x:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols /od
   ```

   Where

   - `/id` is for "input dump"
   - `/s` defines the symbol path. Make sure you get the syntax right. Don't forget to include your company symbol server
   - `/od` is for "output details" (verbose mode) to display any problems