# Error: When I open the executable from "WinDbg", Symbol file could not be found. Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windbg

Issue: I have generated the .msi file (installer) and once I installed that installer when i am trying to open, it is not responding.

To find the root cause, I am using WinDbg and opening the executable (PowerChart.exe) that has generated in the below path:
C:\Program Files\EMR\PowerChart

I followed two approaches to load the executable but in both the approaches i am getting the errors like Symbols are not loading properly.

Approach1:

In the "symbol Search Path", i set `"srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

(For this I created the "symbols" folder in the "C" drive, so that it will download the symbols and place it in "symbols" table)

Then opened the PowerChart.exe from "Open Executable..." in the File menu option of the Windbg.

Then i am getting the below errors:

```
Error: Symbol file could not be found. Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll
```

When i run the URL (https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols) in the browser it is showing "The Data you requested cannot be retrieved"

And also do we need to connect to internet to download these symbols?
Is it the correct symbol path that i have given?
Please help me to resolve this error.

Approach2:

When the .msi file is generated it also generated the .pdb file (EMR.pdb)in the below path:

E:\Code\EMR\bin\debug\en-US

so, what i have done is, I have attached the pdb path in the "symbol Search Path"

E:\Code\EMR\bin\debug\en-US

Then open the PowerChart.exe from "Open Executable..."
Then i am getting the below errors:

```
Error: Symbol file could not be found. Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll

Symbol Loading Error Summary.

Module name Error
ntdll PDB not found  : E:\Code|EMR\bind\debug\en-us\symbols\dll\ntdll.pdb
```

I am not sure whether this approach is correct or not.

Please help me and suggest how to resolve symbol errors?

Comment: IIRC that's nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Be careful with blindly copying the sympath string, sounds to me you forgot to create the c:\symbols directory.  Turn on "noisy mode" so you can see more, as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/verifying-symbols).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up symbols in WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Comment: Use `.symfix c:\symbols` instead of `.sympath` with the URL. Try `!sym noisy` and `.reload /f`. "do we need to connect to internet to download these symbols?" WinDbg does that for you, but it needs an active Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shared I can see that the it is 'ntdll.dll' where you are having an issue. The symbols for that should really be coming from "srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols, but that i sseemingly not happening.

If I may sugest you stick with the second approach and additionally set an envronment variable, i.e. '_NT_SYMBOL_PATH' to 'srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols'.