# Windbg under XP Sp3 cant find symbols and nowhere to download

Tags: windows-xp, windbg, debug-symbols

I try to do some basic learnings for exploit dev, so I setup a Win XP SP3 machine, installed WinDbg for XP from here:

http://www.codemachine.com/downloads.html

I set Symbols path to:

```
srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Then I simply start to debug Windows Media Player wmplayer.exe
When I try to show the !peb, I always get the message that my

**Debugger is not using the correct symbols.**

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up symbols in WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Comment: Try `.reload /f;ld *` after setting the symbol path

Comment: in windbg run `!sym noisy; .reload /f /v` to get more details about symbol loading. post the output. Btw where are you from?