# I can not understand symbol files functioning properly

Tags: virtualbox, windbg, wdk

I'm studying kernel mode driver following to [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF3aYhmfL-0&t=0s&index=3&list=PLZ4EgN7ZCzJx2DRXTRUXRrB2njWnx1kA2) and preparing for debugging a driver in a VirtualBox VM, with WinDbg and Virtual KD.

I set up the symbol file by clicking

1. File / Symbol file path
2. add symbol path

   ```
   SRV*c:\symbols* http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   ```
3. put a check mark to "reload" item
4. click ok

After that, Windbg's screen is as follows:

```
************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*c:\symbols*             http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
kd> .reload
Connected to Windows 10 17134 x64 target at (Sun Oct  7 13:16:30.147 2018     (UTC + 9:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
..........................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
......Unable to enumerate user-mode unloaded modules, Win32 error 0n30
```

I can not understand symbol files functioning properly.

Are Symbol files currently not available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up symbols in WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Comment: It seems you copied a tab or something. The symbol path is not correct after second `*`. Other than that it looks quite ok. All the `....` seems to load a symbol each. Why are you so sure that your symbols don't work? Which command fails?

Comment: I was able to  debug device driver   in virtualbox. Thank you very kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `lml` command in such case.

If symbol files are loaded, you can find module name like this.

```
2: kd> lml
start             end                 module name
ffff9e54`ba960000 ffff9e54`ba9d7000   win32k     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\win32k.pdb\901A464ABCFD2696F50FFB02C607B4661\win32k.pdb
fffff803`6921a000 fffff803`69aef000   nt         (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\9378084E8DBD4AB1A155099BCE693E341\ntkrnlmp.pdb
```

Comment: I was able to  debug device driver   in virtualbox. Thank you very kindly