# How to set WinDbg cache* local symbol path

Tags: windbg

This is my WinDbg target launch link.

From

```
"E:\software\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe" -y SRV*
E:\symbol*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols -b -k com:port=//./pipe/com_1,baud=115200,pipe
```

to

```
"E:\software\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe" -y SRV*[cache*]E:\symbol;D:\projects*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols -b -k com:port=//./pipe/com_1,baud=115200,pipe
```

My local symbolic address is D:\projects, The local pdb file is always locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the HTTP server `SRV*` with the cache `cache*`. And all in all I wonder why you actually need a cache. It doesn't look like you want one. You may have a larger misunderstanding of how a symbol path works. This answer will not go into all details as well.

### Microsoft symbols

Let's begin with the Microsoft symbol server:

```
SRV*E:\symbol*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

- `srv` says that this is a HTTP server.
- `E:\symbol` says where those symbols shall be stored
- `http://...` says where to get the symbols from
- the individual parts of that definition are separated by `*`

### Your own symbols

What you probably want is to have your local symbols (PDB files on your disk) available. You do that with just

- `D:\projects`

and nothing else, where `D:\projects` is a directory which directly contains the PDB files, which is often the case when you build the project locally on your machine.

If your company has a network share, you simply add the network share:

- `srv` to say it's a online resource
- `C:\netsymbols` as your local directory
- `\\ourserver\symbols` for the network share
- the individual parts of that definition are separated by `*` (like before)

If you have a company symbol server via HTTP (like TFS offers), you would use

- `srv` to be a HTTP server.
- `E:\oursymbols` says where those symbols shall be stored (don't put that directory near your source code, e.g. don't use `D:\projects`, because that likely contains your projects, not symbols)
- `http://tfs.example.com/myproject` for your company's server.
- the individual parts of that definition are separated by `*` (like before)

#### Combination of different symbol paths

You can combine different symbol paths using `;`. You typically want to do that in the order of latency and throughput, i.e.

1. Your local hard disk (like `D:\projects`)
2. Your local network (like `srv*C:\netsymbols*\\ourserver\symbols` or local HTTP servers)
3. Internet (like Microsoft HTTP server)

   ```
    D:\projects;srv*C:\netsymbols*\\ourserver\symbols;srv*E:\oursymbols*http://tfs.example.com/myproject;SRV*E:\symbol*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   ```

### The cache

Now, the symbol cache is a harder to grasp concept. It is defined by

```
cache*E:\symbolcache
```

- `cache` is the indicator that you want a cache
- `E:\symbolcache` is where you want the cache to be on hard disk
- the individual parts of that definition are separated by `*` (like before)

The cache will store everything which is right of it. So typically you put that first, giving

```
cache*E:\symbolcache;D:\projects;srv*C:\netsymbols*\\ourserver\symbols;srv*E:\oursymbols*http://tfs.example.com/myproject;SRV*E:\symbol*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

I never used a cache, because I prefer to have individual locations for the different symbols. The cache may be useful if you don't specify HDD locations for each individual part.

### Commands

If you're not sure how to construct a symbol path, take a look at `.symfix` and `.sympath+`. These will help you get a correct Microsoft symbol server as well as combine other paths correctly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg/30019890#30019890) for more examples on symbol paths and how they work.

Comment: Thank you. The problem has been solved. It has bothered me all morning