# Windbg C# dump analysis: how to set debugging symbols?

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

This looks like a question with a very simple answer: just fill in the symbol file path and off you go.
... but it's not that easy:

The name of my C# project is "Application.Customer.Server", and the name of my application (`*.exe file`) is `Application_Server_2.0.exe`.

In my directory `C:\Temp_Folder\`, I have the symbol file, called `Application.Customer.Server.pdb`, and I have set my symbol file path to `C:\Temp_Folder\*`.

Now (after `!sym noisy`), when I launch `lmDvmApplication_server_2_0`, this is what I get:

```
DBGHELP: c:\temp_folder\*\application_server_2_0.dbg - The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
DBGHELP: .\application_server_2_0.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: application_server_2_0 missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: c:\temp_folder\*\application_server_2_0.pdb - file not found
```

Renaming the file has no effect.

How can I load a symbol file, who has a different name than its module?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg Please describe what steps of the linked post you have followed or not. Which `.symfix` and `.sympath` commands have you used?

Comment: `C:\Temp_Folder\*` is not a valid symbol path. Don't add the `*`. The symbol path is a directory name without wildcards.

Comment: If you build the executable on your machine, the EXE contains a link to the PDB and the PDB contain links to the source file. Everything should be found automatically.

Comment: Besides that it's hard to believe that your executable and PDB files have different names. Did you rename your executable?

Comment: As @ThomasWeller said, your symbol path is invalid.