How do I load symbols for an old windows .DLL in WinDbg
I have a crash report that includes the faulting module (ntdll.dll), offset and faulting module version (10.0.17763.5458).  I'd like to find the nearest symbol as a clue to what caused the crash.
Is there somewhere I can download past versions of ntdll.dll?  And if so, how can I get a symbol for the offset?
I tried opening my .exe in WindDbg.   The version of ntdll.dll that is loaded is different (10.0.22621.3527).
Looks like part of the answer is (read-symbols-in-windbg-without-exe), but I need to get the .PDB

Have you configured your symbol path?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg

Yes, symbols are loading correctly.  That isn't the problem.
